# Issue with content generation in outlook email reply

Tags: html, outlook-2010

I am facing an issue with email generated from our application.

In the received email, I do the following

- Ctrl-R (reply)
- Ctrl-A (select-all)
- delete

And I expect to then see an empty outlook email with the correct To: and Subject: lines. The problem is that these actions now lead to an empty box in my email rather than an empty email.

When I debugged the issue, found out that this is because of the following

- Border is given to a div which is hidden.
- In reply mode, this div becomes visible.
- When I do select all and then delete, the box (which is due to
  border to div), doesn't go

Figured that when I change div to span, this problem won't occur. But it is leading to lot of other problems.

Can somebody suggest a solution here. Basically, what I want to achieve is:
Delete all the hidden elements that are not disappearing when I select all and delete

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly sure what you are trying to achieve.
Do you want to delete all the hidden elements that are not disappearing when you select all and delete?

You could try clicking the "Format text" tab, then change from "As HTML" to "As Plain Text" before you choose "Select All".

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This works. I had already informed this to our users. But they are expecting a solution where users don't have to do this.

Comment: Could you attach an example message file so that we can see the actual code?

Comment: The problem was caused by a div at the end. Fixed the issue by adding a line break after that div.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was caused by a div at the end. Fixed the issue by adding a line break after that div